# How to perfectly draw a part of an image in a canvas element using a div selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have not been able to find the solution to the next problem, I have an image with a div over it lets call it "div selector", the div can be dragged by the user. What I want to accomplish is to draw the content of the image that's inside the div, I have written most of the code and I am actually drawing a part of the image but it's not exactly the content of the image that's inside the div selector.

I think the problem is here:

```
let sourceWidth = 137; // previous value: $(sq).width() EDIT: NEW VALUES
let sourceHeight = 137; //previous $(sq).height()
```

As I change those values the part of the image changes but I have not been able to find a calculus that allows the value to change programmatically so if the image height/width changes there would be no problem, the value I currently have 
was found experimenting with another image.

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9j3ypfyh/39/

New jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9j3ypfyh/126/

Thanks a lot for your time.

**EDIT:**
I will also have the option to increase the red square's size, so it should work with different square sizes and also with different canvas sizes as I will make media queries on it.

**EDIT 2**
I added the part which makes the square change its size

**EDIT 3**
I tested the code with the next values:

```
let sourceWidth = $(sq).width();
let sourceHeight = $(sq).width();
```

And I get the next result in a certain screen size (Just what I need!! c:)
[image]
**But** the problem is that if screen size changes it doesn't work anymore :(
[image]

Please help !!

**EDIT**

Is there a way to create a new image based on the selected area and forgetting about drawing the image?

Comment: The problem arises because the canvas renders the image based on its actual dimensions, not the height/width of the image element.  I'm working on adjusting your fiddle to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the problem was caused by the image real size being different than the image element size.  You can use the `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` properties on the image to get the dimensions used by the canvas.

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neze04au/) has the working code.  The relevant part was calculating the ratio of **(real dimension / dom dimension)** and scaling the source values appropriately.

```
        let widthScale = imageObj.naturalWidth / imageObj.width;
        let heightScale = imageObj.naturalHeight / imageObj.height;
        let sourceX = sq.offsetLeft * widthScale;
        let sourceY = sq.offsetTop * heightScale;
        // the -5 and +10 make sure the boundaries of the square match the image element
        let sourceWidth = ($(sq).width() - 5) * widthScale; 
        let sourceHeight = ($(sq).height() + 10) * heightScale;
```

Comment: Great, thank you a lot man. The explanation and solution are so well done, you deserve a lot. Many many Thanks!!!